# Expandable ShareFile Folder Synced to Desktop

Tags: sync

I have synced my SharePoint files so I can view them on my computer. Unlike other folders on my desktop that have arrows to the left of them that I can click on to expand or collapse and see subfolders, I cannot expand the SharePoint folder to view the subfolders within it. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!